# How to pass a parameter as a local variable into a method

Tags: php, class

This may be a very dumb question, but how can I pass a parameter as a local variable in a PHP class.

e.g (this does not work, but represents what I want)

```
public function sql($this->sql_statement){
    // do something 
}
```

I would like the passed parameter to become the '$this->sql_statement' variable

Obviously, I could just do this, but I want to know if there is a better way:

```
public function sql($statement){
    $this->sql_statement = $statement;
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: Do you definitely need $sql_statement to be an object property ($this->sql_statement) or do you need it to be a local variable in that method (which is what your question suggests)?

Comment: @liquorvicar The $sql_statement variable is used throughout the class so it definitely needs to be an object property

Comment: Cool, sounds fine. I was just checking as the question wasn't 100% clear ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that, wanted to keep the code simple for the example :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no better way.  As your method may be called from outside the class, you essentially need to treat it as a standard setter method: set the member variable to the value of the passed parameter, just like in your second code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that is very irritating as it is not very neat code! Oh well, if it is the only way.

Comment: @BenCarey Au contraire, I think this code is neat.  But then I've got a lot of Java background where this is exactly how you are supposed to do this.

Comment: That is very comforting, if I am going to write that code then I will need some support! :-)

Comment: Consider renaming the sql method to something like: setSqlStatement().  That will help make it clear what the method is for.  getters/setters are generally considered to be good things.

Comment: @Cerad I would but the method does a lot more than just this, this is just the beginning of the method